# What is the best way to make an auto increment ID's with large data?

Tags: database

I just want to know what would be the best way or approach to implement an auto increment ID with large amount of data in a database.

My table would actually contains at least hundreds of thousands of data which will be tagged by their unique ID's.

I'm thinking of an alphanumeric ID's which contains prefix at the beginning followed by integer. I am considering the number of characters that should be made but not sure if it will cater even the data will populate more.

Ex of ID I'm thinking is IA00001 then will be incremented by 1 would be IA00002 and so on.

Is it just OK?

I need your suggestions please.

And thanks for advance for any suggestions.

Comment: check this Answer [surrogate vs natural primary keys][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/718200/3836901

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picking the best primary key + numbering system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707657/picking-the-best-primary-key-numbering-system)